# ._where pass array as predicate value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm dynamically assigning an array to predicate in `._where`.

For instance my customized array is as below:

```
arrcolor = [red,green];
```

and my function is

```
testfunction() {
    return ._where(myMainArray, {color: arrcolor });
}
```

But the problem is it is not returning any value even though there is data in `myMainArray` which corresponds to `arrcolor` values.

Comment: can you add a snippet of what you are trying? if it is a string array why you are searching like object? and also what is `._where` it should be `_.where` isn't it?

Comment: How does your "myMainArray" look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I understand what you what to achieve, but as I understand it: I think that myMainArray contains objects that have a color property. You want to get the objects that have either red or green (given from arrcolor)

So myMainArray could look something like this:

```
const myMainArray = [{
  name: 'Item 1',
  color: 'red'
},{
  name: 'Item 2',
  color: 'green'
},{
  name: 'Item 3',
  color: 'blue'
},{
  name: 'Item 4',
  color: 'red'
}];
```

And since `arrcolor = ['red','green']` you want Item 1, Item 2 and Item 4 from myMainArray.

You can achieve that by using `.filter` on myMainArray, which returns a new array that pass the test given by the "filter function".

The test would be that the color property of each object is either red or green.

So something like:

```
const testfunction = function() {
  return myMainArray.filter(obj => arrcolor.includes(obj.color));
}
```

A complete code snippet could like something like:

```js
const arrcolor = ['red','green']

const myMainArray = [{
  name: 'Item 1',
  color: 'red'
},{
  name: 'Item 2',
  color: 'green'
},{
  name: 'Item 3',
  color: 'blue'
},{
  name: 'Item 4',
  color: 'red'
}];

const testfunction = function() {
  return myMainArray.filter(obj => arrcolor.includes(obj.color));
}

const myColors = testfunction()
console.log(myColors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where has been depricated I think you want to use _filter:

```
_.filter(items, {color: myColor})
```

See this issue on [github](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2127)

Answer (score 0):

`_.where` uses `_.isMatch` to compare values, which ultimately does a strict equality check

```
attrs[key] === obj[key]
```

to do the matching. If you pass in an array, like say, `arrcolor`, you're going to be comparing a `color` property in `myMainArr` to the *reference* for `arrcolor`.

That essentially means that the only time you'll actually get a match is if the property in one object was used to store the **exact same**array as the array you're matching for. So, let's assume that when you do this

arrcolor =  ['red', 'green'] //JS stores this array to some memory location, say 0xA19 – arrcolor is a pointer I that stores a reference to that memory location

and let's assume that

```
myMainArray[0].color = ['red', 'green'] // And here JS stores this NEW array to some other memory location, say 0xA1F
```

They're, you'll see that

```
myMainArray[0].color === arrcolor // false
```

Since the equality operator (`==` or `===) will only compare the references, not the values inside the array.

Finally, if you want to filter only `myMainArray` items that have **both** colors, assuming that `myMainArray[0].color` is an array of colors, you'd use the following

```
_.filter(myMainArray, function (item) {
  return _.all(arrcolor, function (color) {
    return _.any(item.color, function (mainColor) { return mainColor == color; });
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its right or not but I have done this:

looped through **arrcolor** and then used the following:

return ._where(myMainArray, {color: arrcolor[i] });

It worked!!!